# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1024,1) into shape (1024,)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to replace the first column with a column array?

```
nz = 10
FWHM = 25
nt = 2 ** 10
dt = FWHM / nt
t = (np.array(range(1, nt + 1)).reshape(nt, 1) - (nt + 1) / 2) * dt
t0 = 0
C = 0
m = 1
P0 = 0.00064

# u0
u0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(t), nz ))
u0[:, 0] = math.sqrt(P0) * 2 ** (-((1 + 1j * C) / 2) * (2 * (t - t0) / FWHM) ** (2 * m))
```

Comment: What's `nz`? You can use `np.squeeze()` for the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the last instruction in your code sample:

```
u0[:, 0] = ...
```

and note that *u0[:, 0].shape* is *(1024,)*.
So what you attempt to write there should also be a **1-dimensional** array
(also with shape *(1024,)*.

To do it, define *t* array as **1-dimensional** (remove *.reshape(nt, 1)*):

```
t = (np.array(range(1, nt + 1)) - (nt + 1) / 2) * dt
```

Another detail to correct is to define *u0* as of **complex** type:

```
u0 = np.zeros(shape=(len(t), nz), dtype=complex)
```

Otherwise the imaginary part will be dropped (but fortunately, with a suitable warning).